# Does Latest Spring Data MongoDB Support Bitwise Query?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm on my first project on MongoDB, and I'm using spring-data-mongodb as the ORM. The spring-data-mongodb is quite powerful, but I couldn't find any materials about MongoDB's [bitwise query operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-bitwise/) in it, and I want to know whether bitwise query is supported in the latest spring-data-mongodb.

PS: I have found the spring-data-mongodb does support [bitwise update](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Update.BitwiseOperatorBuilder.html), so I think bitwise query should also be supported.

Comment: Technically speaking, every single driver **always** supports every available server feature, and it does this through the "wire protocol" which has basically not changed. Now "Spring MongoDB" is not even a "driver", per-se. But instead is another "abstraction" on top of the Java Driver, which gives you some helper and convenience methods. So just because there isn't something like `.bitsAllSet()` to modify a `Criteria` object, does not mean you cannot perform the query itself. You can afterall supply a `BasicDBObject` to query. And there is the `BasicQuery` type which does exactly that.